# How can I simulate Alt+Shift to change the language in Windows?

Tags: delphi, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

i need to to force alt + shift in Delphi to make my language of the app. I tried with keybd_event calling it twice, but it didn't do the trick.

Comment: You don't, for two reasons: the user might have disabled this keyboard shortcut, and messing around the user settings without her/his consent is a no-no.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you want to switch input language of your application? Use [ActivateKeyboardLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function for this.

Answer (score 2):

Do you control the system to be sure that it's going to respond to that?  I have an alternate language installed but it can only be switched via the mouse, I have disabled the keyboard shortcuts.  The problem is that I rarely actually need the alternate but I was frequently switching by accident.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that messing with a user's preferences is rarely a good idea and might end up with doing lots of unexpected things.