# How can I simulate Alt+Shift to change the language in Windows (II part)?

Tags: delphi, keyboard-shortcuts, delphi-2009, keyboard-layout

The problem (switching language dynamically) is solved with [ActivateKeyboardLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607323/how-can-i-simulate-altshift-to-change-the-language-in-windows), but it still remains when i dynamically create a component on the form ( for ex. TEdit ). When this component gets into focus, the language changes to default. I tried use again ActivateKeyboardLayout, after creating the components, but it did not worked. Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you use KLF_SETFORPROCESS?

Comment: @TOndrej: I used it like this: LoadKeyboardLayout(someId, KLF_ACTIVATE)

Comment: Cannot duplicate, my dynamically created Edit preserves the changed layout. Can you post a sample that have the problem?

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz: I have a dbgrid on the form. When I create the Edit dynamically I set the parent to dbgrid. The initial call of LoadKeyboardLayout is onActivate.

Comment: I think your problem is related with a known problem. See the QC report #79485: [Keyboard layout swtching when exiting dbgrid control](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=79485). And see [this thread](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=180475&tstart=0#180475) on embarcadero forums for a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first you have to use "Windows" then you can use this method:
ActivateKeyboardLayout(EnglishLayoutHandle, KLF_ACTIVATE)
you can change "EnglishLayoutHandle" for any lang you want

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756357/disable-automatic-changing-of-keyboard-layout).

Otherwise this code does it:

```delphi
keybd_event(VK_MENU, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0 );
keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

Comment: This code switches to next input language (and only if the default shortcuts have not been changed). It won't help if you have more than two input languages

Answer (score 0):

On the Console application use

```
HWND handle = GetForegroundWindow();
PostMessage(handle, WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST,
            0, (LPARAM)HKL_NEXT);
```