# disable automatic changing of keyboard layout in DbGrids.pas in VCL

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, keyboard-layout

I use `ActivateKeyboardLayout(HKL_NEXT, KLF_ACTIVATE);` to load Persian keyboard layout using Delphi XE2, But sometimes I click on TextBox or DbGrid control the keyboard automatically is changed to English layout.

How can I disable automatic changing of keyboard layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have same issues. This bug appeared after upgrade from D2006 to D2010.

Issue is in DBGrids.pas:

```
procedure TCustomDBGrid.WMKillFocus(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  ImeName := Screen.DefaultIme;
  ImeMode := imDontCare;
  inherited;
  if not ((InplaceEditor <> nil) and
    (HWND(Message.WParam) = InplaceEditor.Handle)) then
    ActivateKeyboardLayout(Screen.DefaultKbLayout, KLF_ACTIVATE);
end;
```

I have no idea why Borland/Embarcadero added "if block" after inherited. Change causes switching keyboard layout back to default. We had to copy DBGrids to our projects and remove "if block".